# how to add model name in the start of json from api server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

im working on ember.js project. when i create record of user model it created successfully but api server response me with newly created record json properties in this form

```
{
  firstname : 'Ateek',
  lastname: 'pervaiz'
}
```

basically i wants to change this json formate into this one

```
{
  user: {
   firstname : 'Ateek',
   lastname: 'pervaiz'
   }
}
```

so that my ember project can understand that this json response is for user model.
so please tell me that which method of serializer i can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to override the `normalizeSaveResponse` hook.

See the docs here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeSaveResponse